# How to rename filenames with accents on macOS?

Tags: osx, regular-expression, rename, unicode, locate

I am trying to rename files that include the character "à".

I do the following :

```
rename -v 's/à/a/g' *
```

But it shows all the files as unchanged. Verbose mode shows the same thing.

I tried to escape with `\` but with no luck.

How can I make the regex match this type of character ?

EDIT

The output of `perl -V` :

```
Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 18 subversion 2) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=darwin, osvers=16.0, archname=darwin-thread-multi-2level
    uname='darwin osx320.apple.com 16.0 darwin kernel version 15.0.0: wed jun 22 17:57:08 pdt 2016; root:xnu-3247.1.106.2.9~1development_x86_64 x86_64 '
    config_args='-ds -e -Dprefix=/usr -Dccflags=-g  -pipe  -Dldflags= -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseithreads -Duseshrplib -Dinc_version_list=none -Dcc=cc'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='cc', ccflags ='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector',
    optimize='-Os',
    cppflags='-g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='cc -mmacosx-version-min=10.12.5', ldflags ='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -fstack-protector'
    libpth=/usr/lib /usr/local/lib
    libs= 
    perllibs=
    libc=, so=dylib, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.dylib
    gnulibc_version=''
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=bundle, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags=' '
    cccdlflags=' ', lddlflags='-arch x86_64 -arch i386 -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -fstack-protector'


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV
                        PERL_HASH_FUNC_ONE_AT_A_TIME_HARD
                        PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT PERL_MALLOC_WRAP
                        PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV PERL_SAWAMPERSAND USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API
  Locally applied patches:
    /Library/Perl/Updates/<version> comes before system perl directories
    installprivlib and installarchlib points to the Updates directory
  Built under darwin
  Compiled at Feb  6 2017 22:16:22
  @INC:
    /Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Library/Perl/5.18
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /Network/Library/Perl/5.18
    /Library/Perl/Updates/5.18.2
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/5.18
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level
    /System/Library/Perl/Extras/5.18
    .
```

EDIT 2 :

Output of `locale` :

```
LANG=
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
```

**SOLUTION**

Here's in a nutshell what worked. All the 3 solution did the job :

1. `rename -nv $'s/a\xcc\x80/a/g' *`
2. `PERL_UNICODE=AS rename -n 's/\pM//g' ./*`. (see explanations in chosen answer)
3. Switching to `zsh`, instead of the default Shell of MacOS (`bash`), then my original command (without any need for specifying combining characters such as `a\u300`) worked : `rename -v 's/à/a/g' *`.

If you're not satisfied with either of these solutions, please look at the chosen answer to find useful tips.

Comment: It works fine on my Debian. I'm not sure what this depends on, but if you post the value of `$LANG`, it might be helpful. Also `perl -V`.

Comment: What implementation/version of `rename`?

Comment: If using the util-linux implementation of `rename` (as opposed to the perl-based ones), the syntax is `rename -v à a ./*`

Comment: It says version 1.600. I am using a Mac actually.@tomas, I edited the post including perl -V but $LANG returns nothing.

Comment: So it seems to be [this](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/) perl-based rename (there's also at least [this one](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Unicode-Tussle-1.111/lib/Unicode/Tussle.pm) and [this one](http://search.cpan.org/~rmbarker/File-Rename-0.20/lib/File/Rename.pm). What's the output of `locale`? Are the files matched by `ls -d *à*`? Does `-T utf8` help?

Comment: @Gilles I updated the post with `locale` info. The file aren't matched by `ls -d *à*` either and `-T utf8` as well as `-T utf-8` throw the following error : "Use of uninitialized value $out_enc in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/bin/rename line 149.
No such encoding "

Comment: Try with `ls -d -- *$'\xcc\x80'*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On macOS and with the HFS+ file system at least, accented characters are encoded in their decomposed form so `à` is encoded as `a\u300` (`a` followed by the *combining grave accent* [combining character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character)) even if you created the file with `touch $'\ue0'` (the pre-composed form (stand-alone `a` with grave accent), causing all sorts of bugs (and subject of [one of Linus Torvald's famous rants](https://www.cio.com/article/251059/linus-torvalds-apples-hfs-is-probably-the-worst-file-system-ever.html)) like for its pseudo-case insensitiveness.

You'll notice that if you do:

```
touch à; echo ?
```

to list the file names made of one character, it returns nothing while:

```
echo ??
```

or

```
echo *a*
```

Does return that `à` (actually `à`). And:

```
$ echo ?? | uconv -x name
\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER A}\N{COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT}\N{<control-000A>}
```

So you'd need:

```
rename $'s/a\u300/a/g' ./*
```

(assuming `zsh` or compatible shell). Or using specifying the UTF-8 encoding of that U+0300 character (0xcc 0x80) by hand, for shells that support the ksh93 `$'...'` quotes but not `zsh`'s `$'\u300'` (like the ancient version of `bash` found on macOS):

```
rename $'s/a\xcc\x80/a/g' ./*
```

Or let `perl` interpret those `\xcc\x80` sequences directly:

```
rename 's/a\xcc\x80/a/g' ./*
```

Or the unicode character:

```
PERL_UNICODE=AS rename 's/\x{300}//' ./*
```

Or remove all combining characters with:

```
PERL_UNICODE=AS rename -n 's/\pM//g' ./*
```

There, we're telling `perl` to consider `A`rguments and `S`tdio streams are encoded in UTF-8 (see `perldoc perlrun` for a description of the `$PERL_UNICODE` env var equivalent to the `-C` option) and remove all the characters that have the `M`ark Unicode `p`roperty (`\pM` is short for `\p{Mark}` or `\p{Combining_Mark}`, see `perldoc perluniprops` for details)

Note that you should be able to list that file (in `zsh`) both with:

```
ls -d $'a\u300'
```

and:

```
ls -d $'\ue0'
```

(and `$'A\u300' and possibly $'\uc0` for `À` as it's meant to be case insensitive), but:

```
ls -d *A*
```

and in shells other than `zsh`:

```
ls -d *$'\ue0'*
ls -d *$'\xc3\xa0'*
```

won't match it, because the shell lists the content of the current directory and applies the pattern against each file name and the file name is encoded as `a\u300` which won't match.

On `zsh` however and on macOS only, the shell internally converts those letters with combining accents to their precomposed form upon `readdir()` as if passing them through `iconv -f UTF-8-MAC -t UTF-8`. [Its own internal `zreaddir()` wrapper around `readdir()`](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/85e56b5a48a2d83736fa367173fab4173551c8cf/tree/Src/utils.c#l4956) does return U+00E0 instead of `aU+0300` which explains why `echo *à*` works there (and not `echo *a*`) and not elsewhere.

The change was introduced in June 2014. See the [discussion on the zsh mailing list for more details](https://www.zsh.org/mla/workers/2014/msg00444.html).

The core of the problem is the discrepancy between the encoding used on user input and the one used to store (and list) file names in the file system. The problem is a lot worse in Korean where virtually every character has a precomposed and decomposed form, which explains why the zsh issue was raised by a Korean person initially.

So `zsh` basically *fixes* Apple's poor choice of decomposed form in the file system so its completion and globs can be used, but unfortunately, that only applies to `zsh`, `ls | grep à` or `find . -name '*à*'` still won't work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sound promising but still had no chances ...
I could not try the uconv line because it's not installed on Mac OS I guess.
I tried `rename -nv $'s/a\u300/a/g'` but got "Using expression: sub { use feature ':5.18'; s/a\u300/a/g } filename-à.png unchanged" T~T.
Not sure what means zsh tho. I am using default Mac Terminal.

Comment: @lapin That error message suggests your shell doesn't support `\u300`. Try switching to `zsh` which should be available on macOS or use `\xcc\x80` in place of `\u300`.

Comment: What is `echo ?` ? I did `touch à; echo ?` in one terminal and now `echo ?` prints `à` in ALL open terminals.

Comment: @tomas `touch à` created a blank file named `à` in $PWD, which was presumably your default directory. `?` is a wildcard for exactly one character (`??` is exactly two characters, etc.). Your shell expands `?` into that single-character filename before `echo` gets to it. Since you only have the one single-character file present, `echo ?` is expanded to `echo à`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Okay. Thanks so much. Impressive Shell knowledge lol. Some solution worked, I'll update the post to explain which one.
Then I'll choose your answer. But please could you explain : 1) : How could anyone solves his own encoding problems and come across this type of solution `\xcc\x80`, where does that come from ? 2) What does `PERL_UNICODE=AS rename -n 's/\pM//g' ./*` so exactly ?

Comment: @lapin, see edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I chose your answer and edited my post to include what worked. Notice that when using zsh, there was no need to specify any combining character, it just worked. Merci beaucoup !!

Comment: @lapin. I can't explain how that can work with `zsh`. The only explanation I can think of is that apple patched `zsh` and not `bash` to automatically transform `à` to `à` upon input, or `à` to `à` upon glob expansion. What do you get for `echo à | od -tx1` (where you type that à on the keyboard) in bash and zsh?

Comment: I get the following : 
`echo à | od -tx1 
0000000    c3  a0  0a                                                    
0000003` and I typed it by keyboard without copypaste but I get same result when I copypaste it.

Comment: @lapin, in both `zsh` and `bash`? What about `touch à; echo * | od -tx1` in an empty directory on an HFS+ file system? (in both bash and zsh)?

Comment: Yes in both `zsh` and `bash`. For this command however I get : same as before for `zsh` and the following for `bash` : `0000000    61  cc  80  0a                                                
0000004`

Comment: @lapin, and same for `ls | od -tx1`? That would seem to confirm that in `zsh` but not `bash`, the `aU+0300` decomposed form as returned by readdir is somehow converted to `U+00E0` (precomposed form `à`). How odd.

Comment: @lapin, see edit, zsh does that indeed on Mac.