# Batch remove invisible characters from filenames

Tags: scripting, macos

I have hundreds of files on external drive that were probably copied a lot, and likely recovered at some time too. The filenames seem tho have acquired some weird characters over their lifespan and I need to fix them.

The problem is that I can list them with `ls`, but I can't do anything to them by referring to their names.

`ls -l` renders this result:

```
-rwx------  1 krzysztof  staff  322451 Jun 27  2009 file015.jpg
-rwx------  1 krzysztof  staff  331337 Jun 27  2009 file016.jpg
-rwx------  1 krzysztof  staff  303078 Jun 27  2009 file017.jpg
-rwx------  1 krzysztof  staff  312346 Jun 27  2009 file018.jpg
```

The files themselves are not corrupted, and if I manually change the name, the problem goes away. I can also create a file with seemingly exactly the same name (and both will be displayed at the same time with `ls`). This lead me to believe that there is something fishy going on with invisible characters, which I confirmed by running `find . -name '*[! -~]*'` - it returned a list of all problematic files.

I wouldn't care about these names normally, but some applications and tools apparently have problem with them too, and just straight up don't see them or ignore them.

One example would be a `detox` tool that I first attempted to fix the names with - it just pretended they don't exist.

`exiftool` throws `No such file or directory`. Similarly, piping the `ls -1` to a loop, or saving the file names to a file and then piping them always results in various forms `No such file or directory`. Like if the invisible characters were not preserved when piping or saving?

```
$ while read p; do
  mv "$p" "$p"
done <`find . -name '*.jpg'`
zsh: no such file or directory: ./file015.jpg
```

Is there any way to clean the filenames in batch?

##### EDIT 1:

Per @terdon request I tried `ls -v` and `ls -B` - nothing shows up.

However, the `ls | head -n1 | od -c` is more interesting, and led me to a discovery of my own too. Here I owe you an apology, because in my original question I changed the names as I thought it didn't matter, but it does.

With that, here is the actual output, where file 014 was fixed manually, and the rest is broken:

```
❯ ls -1
Zdjęcie014.jpg
Zdjęcie015.jpg
Zdjęcie016.jpg
Zdjęcie017.jpg
Zdjęcie018.jpg
```

And here is `ls | head -n2 | od -c` - I used `n2` to show more than first filename.

```
❯ ls | head -n2 | od -c
0000000    Z   d   j   e    ̨  **   c   i   e   0   1   4   .   j   p   g
0000020   \n   Z   d   j   e    ̨  **   c   i   e   0   1   5   .   j   p
0000040    g  \n
0000042
```

[image]

As you can see there is a `ę` character in both files, and it seems to be the same in `ls | head -n2 | od -c`. But! When I went back to edit and rename the files manually, in 014 (fixed file) when I position cursor after `ę` and hit backspace, the entire character disappears. This is not the case for other files - pressing backspace on `ę` changes it to `e`, and only second backspace removes it.

Thank you @terdon - now we know where the problem is. How can this be fixed in batch?

##### EDIT 2:

014 is fixed, 015 is broken:

```
❯ ls | head -n2 | LC_ALL=C sed -n l
Zdje\314\250cie014.jpg$
Zdje\314\250cie015.jpg$
```

##### EDIT 3:

As suggested in comments, I attempted to apply solution from [How to rename filenames with accents on macOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399927/how-to-rename-filenames-with-accents-on-macos#400104) but again run into the `No such file or directory`

```
❯ rename $'s/\u119/e/g' ./*
Can't rename './Zdjęcie015.jpg' to './Zdjecie015.jpg': No such file or directory
```

`rename $'s/\u0328//g' ./*` does nothing both in bash and zsh

##### EDIT 4:

```
❯ PERL_UNICODE=ASD find . -depth -execdir rename -n 's/\pM//g' {} +
'Zdjęcie015.jpg' would be renamed to 'Zdjecie015.jpg'
```

and

```
❯ PERL_UNICODE=ASD find . -depth -execdir rename 's/\pM//g' {} +
Can't rename 'Zdjęcie015.jpg' to 'Zdjecie015.jpg': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139382/discussion-on-question-by-devligue-batch-remove-invisible-characters-from-filena).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this really is an answer as I wasn't able to make it work from macOS, but it certainly is a workaround that solved my problem.

Since the external drive was a NAS, I ssh'ed into it and fixed the problem directly. Unfortunately fancy tools like `rename` were unavailable to me, so I had to craft something using `find`, `mv` and `sed` - and it worked just right!

Here is the command I used:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.JPG" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | sed s/Zdj.*cie/zdjecie/)"' _ {} \;
```

P.S. Thanks to the heroes from the comment section for helping along the way!